# clear timeout when second settimeout called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 5 settimeouts. i want to clear the firstone when second one is called. and so on...
help me guys???

Comment: `var timeout = setTimeout(animate4, 11000);
clearTimeout(timeout);`

Comment: @jfriend00 Haha yeah, I'm an idiot. I knew that, but for some reason didn't care to use that

Comment: You ask what do you want? Or if we should help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var timeout1 = setTimeout(animate5, 1000);
var timeout2 = setTimeout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout1);
    animate4();
}, 11000);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var timeout1 = setTimeout(animate5, 1000);
var timeout2 = setTimeout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout1);
    animate4();
}, 11000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var t5 = setTimeout(animate5, 1000);
var t4 = setTimeout(animate4, 11000);
var t3 = setTimeout(animate3, 21000);
var t2 = setTimeout(function() {
    clearTimeout(t1);
    animate2();
}, 31000);
var t1 = setTimeout(animate1, 41000);
```